# javascript text input as variable name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple site which populates the textarea with the value of the variable, and this variable user would provide as a string in a separate text field. Exceptions aside I am struggling with displaying.

So I defined the variables in the separate .js file that has been linked in the site header:

```
var var01 = 'variable01 value';
var var02 = 'variable02 value';
var var03 = 'variable03 value';
var var04 = 'variable04 value';
var var05 = 'variable05 value';
var var06 = 'variable06 value';
var var07 = 'variable07 value';
var var08 = 'variable08 value';
var var09 = 'variable09 value';
var var10 = 'variable10 value';
```

The HTML part I managed to put together is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ShowValue(x) {
document.Entries.ValueField.value = x.value;
}
</script>
<form name="Entries">
<p>Enter the value:</p>
<input type="text" name="VariableID" id="VariableID">
<input id="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ShowValue(VariableID);">
<br>
<textarea name="ValueField" rows="40" cols="60"></textarea>
</form>
```

What the code does ATM is populating the textarea with the text provided: when I enter "variable10" it returns "variable10" not "variable10 value". What am I missing?

PS: I need this at work and we have a lot of addresses blocked by GPO, so I avoid using external libraries.

Comment: You better get familar with [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array). Also, direct reference by name is not recommended, use e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName` method or `forms` collection instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - doing it now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Eval function to get the value.

```
eval(x.value)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fqw0hfgj/10/

Comment: Thank you - looks like this simple solution solved my problem! :)